# buzz follower using yql

Tags: yql, google-buzz

HI

how can i grab buzz follower using YQL . actually i want to count the total no of buzz follower . please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to [obtain an OAuth access token for Google Buzz first](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html#authentication) because the access points for obtaining followers require authentication.  Then, instead of the usual methods of passing in an OAuth signature to the Buzz API, you would do it through the URI with query parameters.  This will allow you to craft the URI and pass it through to YQL, which will in turn relay it to the Buzz API.  You will, of course, need to generate your YQL query dynamically.  Then you can make the API call to get the list of [Buzz followers](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html#people-followers).

Please note, OAuth is hard, and this is probably very nearly the hardest possible usage of OAuth I can think of.  Not for the feint of heart.  In this case, YQL is going to make things much more complicated, not less complicated.

Comment: is there any other solution to get total follower not from the yql but from other means e. jquery ?

Comment: That would make it ever-so-slightly easier, but it's still in the realm of pretty hard.  The current API relies on OAuth for authentication, which means you have to redirect the user to a page hosted by Google before you can make API calls.  It also means that you need to store tokens somewhere, and that realistically means either server-side persistence or HTML5 local storage.  You could store the token in a cookie if you don't mind going through the OAuth flow again every time the cookie expires or your users clear their cookies.  OAuth APIs work best in a server-side environment.